# Determine the value of $\cos(2)$

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry, taylor-expansion

I'm trying to prove that the function $f(x)=\cos(x)$ has an $x$-intercept in the interval $[0,2]$. To do that I showed that $f(0)=\cos(0)=1>0$. Then I would have to show that $\cos(2)<0$, however how would I workout the value of $\cos(2)$? My professor mentioned something about using the Taylor Polynomial but I'm not sure.

Comment: @MathLover I suspect that that's cheating, because I suspect that the point to the problem is to first show that $\cos$ has a positive zero, and then they're going to _define_ $\pi=2\alpha$, where $\alpha$ is the smallest positive zero of $\cos$.  See for example the Prologue to Rudin "Real and Complex Analysis", or the appendix on trig functions in "Complex Made Simple". (In any case, _if_ we already know that $\cos(\pi/2)=0$ then a problem asking us to show that $\cos$ has a zero doesn't make much sense...)

Comment: Probably you should clarify that you've just defined $\cos$ using the power series, so the only thing you're allowed to use is that series. (Otherwise you're going to get answers assuming we know about $\cos(\pi/2)=0$, which are missing the point.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Curiously, in my Analysis I class, $\pi/2$ was *defined* as the first positive zero of the $\cos$ function, so the existence of such a zero had to be first shown. $\cos$ was defined as the even part of the exponential function, which was defined using a Taylor series.

On the off chance you're in a similar scenario where you can only use the Taylor expansion and no properties of $\pi$:
$$\begin{align}\cos x= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!} x^{2n}&=1-\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}-\dots \\
\cos x &< 1-\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^4}{4!} \\
\cos 2 &< 1-\frac{4}{2!}+\frac{16}{4!}=-\frac{1}{3}<0\end{align}$$
as required.

As David C. Ullrich states in the comments, it's not immediately clear that the inequality I've written above holds. However, using arguments about alternating series, it's not difficult to show true for $x^2 < 30$, which is all that's required here.

Comment: Yes! That's exactly the one I was looking for! But where did you get the first line equation from? I'm only familiar from the second line on.

Comment: The first line is the Taylor expansion of the cosine function, written more compactly. If you're only familiar with $1 - \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^4}{4!} - \frac{x^6}{6!} + \dots$ the argument isn't changed.

Comment: The other answers are missing the point (not that the point was explicitly spelled out in the problem). Thought I was gonna have to write this up myself... But NOTE that the inequality you state for $\cos(x)$ doesn't hold without restrictions on $x$; it's fine for $x=2$. (Or maybe it does hold for all $x$, but this isn't clear using nothing but the power series...)

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Good point! I'll amend my answer.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: It does hold for all $x\neq 0$, but is not a direct consequence of the Taylor. Let's say it's based on analysis of Remainder in Lagrange form and moreover requires proving that both $\sin, \cos$ are bounded in absolute value by $1$. And fully agree with your point about other answers. Perhaps the OP should add some more context in the question.

Answer (score 4):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\cos\pars{2} & = \cos\pars{{2\pi \over 3} + \bracks{2 - {2\pi \over 3}}}
\\[5mm] & =
\overbrace{\cos\pars{2\pi \over 3}}^{\ds{-\,{1 \over 2}}}\
\overbrace{\cos\pars{6 - 2\pi \over 3}}^{\ds{\approx\ 1}}\ -\
\overbrace{\sin\pars{2\pi \over 3}}^{\ds{\root{3} \over 2}}\
\overbrace{\sin\pars{6 - 2\pi \over 3}}^{\ds{\approx\ {6 - 2\pi \over 3}}}
\\[5mm] & \approx
\bbx{{2\root{3}\pi - 6\root{3} - 3 \over 6} \approx -0.4183}\label{1}\tag{1}
\end{align}

> A calculator yields $\ds{\cos\pars{2} = -0.416146836547142\ldots}$.
>   The \eqref{1} *relative error* is $\ds{\color{red}{\large0.5057\ \%}}$.

Answer (score 3):

$2$ is between $\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $\pi$, so $\cos(2)$ is certainly negative. For a numerical determination of such constant, one may invoke
$$ \forall x\in\mathbb{R},\qquad \cos(x)=\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n x^{2n}}{(2n)!}.\tag{A}$$
By evaluating the RHS at $x=2$ and truncating at $n=3$, we get $\cos(2)\approx -\frac{19}{45}$.

There are more efficient methods, however. For instance,

$$\cos(2)=2\cos^2(1)-1=8\cos^4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)-8\cos^2\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)+1$$
and by $(A)$ the constant $\cos\frac{1}{2}$ is pretty simple to approximate: it is about $\frac{337}{384}$.

Comment: That makes sense but $cos(2)≤1-\frac{2^2}{2!}+\frac{2^4}{4!}=-\frac{1}{3}<0$ also make sense?

Comment: @SkiMask: sure.

Answer (score 1):

Simply notice that $$ \frac{\pi}{2} < \frac{3.2}{2} = 1.6 < 2 < \pi$$

Since $\cos$ is stricly decreasing on the interval $[\frac{\pi}{2}, \pi]$, we conclude $\cos(2) < \cos(\frac{\pi}{2})$.

Alternatively, if you want to use the power series, recall that $\cos(x) = \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n (x)^{2n}}{(2n)!} $.

Now, notice that $\frac{-(2)^{4k-2}}{(4k-2)!} + \frac{(2)^{4k}}{(4k)!} < 0$ for $ k \in \mathbb{N}$.

Thus $\cos(2) < \sum\limits_{n=0}^2 \frac{(-1)^n (2)^{2n}}{(2n)!} = 1 - \frac{4}{2} + \frac{16}{24} < 0$.

Answer (score 1):

*Just for the fun of it.*

Using the same idea as Felix Marin, let us build the $[n,n]$ Padé approximant of $\cos \left(x+\frac{2\pi }{3}\right)$ around $x=0$ and evaluate it for $x=2-\frac{2\pi }{3}$.

For $n=1$
$$-\frac{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{7 }{4 \sqrt{3}} x}{1+\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{3}}x }\implies \cos(2)\approx -\frac{9+21 \sqrt{3}-7 \sqrt{3} \pi }{18+6 \sqrt{3}-2 \sqrt{3} \pi }\approx -0.415961$$ which corresponds to a relative error of $\color{red}{\text{0.04455 %}}$.

For $n=2$
$$-\frac{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{17 }{12 \sqrt{3}}x-\frac{19 }{72}x^2 } { 1-\frac{1}{6 \sqrt{3}}x+\frac{5 }{36}x^2}\implies \cos(2)\approx \frac{90-153 \sqrt{3}-114 \pi +51 \sqrt{3} \pi +19 \pi ^2}{252-18 \sqrt{3}-60 \pi
   +6 \sqrt{3} \pi +10 \pi ^2}\approx -0.416147$$ which corresponds to a relative error of $\color{red}{\text{0.00003 %}}$.